# how to get info of second sim in android

Tags: android, android-permissions, dual-sim

By using this below method i am getting information of sim one

```
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            // Get the SIM country ISO code
            String simCountry = telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso();
            Log.e("Show:", simCountry);
            // Get the operator code of the active SIM (MCC + MNC)
            String simOperatorCode = telephonyManager.getSimOperator();
            Log.e("Show:", simOperatorCode);
            // Get the name of the SIM operator
            String simOperatorName = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
            Log.e("Show:", simOperatorName);
            // Get the SIM’s serial number
            String simSerial = telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();
            Log.e("Show:", simSerial);
            // Get the phone number
            String mPhoneNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
            Log.e("Show:", mPhoneNumber);
```

how to get information of second sim of dual sim phone?

```
            // Get the phone number
            String mPhoneNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
            Log.e("Show:", mPhoneNumber);
```

work on some device

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

So what should i do? Is there any Mistake?

Answer (score 0):

From Android API 22 [SubscriptionMananger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html) is available
You just need to call

`SubscriptionManager.from(context).getActiveSubscriptionInfo(1)`

to get info about second sim card